# Difference between LinkedList of Object and a LinkedList of a HashMap?

Tags: java, linked-list, hashmap

I was coding some Java code and i saw that i couldn't do that :

```
LinkedList<HashMap<String,Object>> errorManagement = new LinkedList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
HashMap<String,Object> i = new HashMap<String,Object>();
errorManagement.add(i.clone()); <-- impossible to add the hash map here
```

Where i was getting some errors if i wanted to add an hash map to my linked list ...

And i figured out that by doing in that way:

```
HashMap<String,Object> tokenInfo = new HashMap<String,Object>();
LinkedList<Object> errorManagement = new LinkedList<Object>();
errorManagement.add(tokenInfo.clone()); <-- everything working like a charm !
```

I hadn't any more errors.
May someone explain me why ? And what's the difference ?

P.S. : I should say ,before someone asks me, that the error was thrown when i was adding anything to my linked list (for the first example)!

Comment: Have you checked the return type of `clone` already?

Comment: It would be helpful if you pasted the exception stack trace. Besides: you can write `HashMap<String,Object> i = new HashMap<>();`... no need to repeat the type information.

Comment: @EddyG It's a compiler error.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Well, then you must be using Java 1.6; the diamond operator was introduced with 1.7; and the line I just posted is perfectly fine.

Comment: @EddyG *OP*'s error is a compiler error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the return type of `clone()`: it's `Object`, not `HashMap<String,Object>`. That's why the second snippet works, but the first one does not.

You can fix the first code snippet by constructing a copy of hash map through a constructor:

```
errorManagement.add(new HashMap<String,Object>(i));
```

Answer (score 1):

Object is parent of every class by default and hence HashMap is of type Object and hence you would be able to add child of Object i.e. HashMap.

Another thing is clone return type is Object and hence even if you type cast it back to HashMap, you should be able to do the same.

So if you want to get rid of error, then you should change

```
 errorManagement.add(i.clone());
```

To

```
errorManagement.add((HashMap)i.clone());
```